# Windows Server 2019 goes down and loses connection every few day. Ideas on how to diagnose?

Tags: windows, networking, hardware, hosting, windows-server-2019

I have a hosted dedicated Windows Server 2019 that is going down every few days. Randomly all of the websites that are hosted via IIS/PHP/MySQL will just stop working (going to the www.domain.com will just hang and timeout) and I won't be able to RDP remote into the machine. I know it's not just IIS going down, because RDP stops working too.

Rebooting the machine via my hosts web console solves the problem, at least for a few more days. And the problem with the reboot is that it isn't a clean reboot, which could cause me some data corruption.

I've had my hosting company log in at the physical machine itself, and when they do it looks like the NIC is fine and the connection comes back online for some reason.

I'm having problems understanding where the problem is.... is it a problem with the NIC itself? The cable? Or is some piece of software running on my server causing some kind of overload that crashes the network interface/drivers?

I notice nothing out of the ordinary in the event logs that I can see, and there is no "crash dump" that I can see happening either, although maybe I'm not looking in the correct places for more information.

**I'm looking for ideas on how to diagnose a problem like this. Is it a software problem caused by me? Or a hardware problem on my hosting companies side?**

Answer (score 0):

From your description it can be anything. To go forward:

1. check the Windows event log - does the system actually hang when losing access? are there license/activation issues?
2. check the hardware event log - anything? does the server have lights-out management?
3. have the ISP check the uplink switch event log (does the link actually go
   down?)